# Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 106--107

Tags: warnings

Recently, LaTeX always shows

`"Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 106--107`

Trial:

```
   \documentclass{ctexart}
   \usepackage{color}
   \usepackage{amsmath}
   \usepackage{amssymb}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage{epstopdf}
   \hfuzz=\maxdimen
   \tolerance=10000
   \hbadness=10000
   \begin{document}

$(A \pm  B)^{-1} \neq A^{-1} \pm B^{-1}$,$(A \pm  B)^* \neq A^* \pm B^*$~\
$|(A^*)^*|=|A|^{n^2-2 n+1}$~\
\end {document}
```

My question :How to revise it?

And I found the code that cotains the `"~\\"` and `blank line`  always shows the warning imformation `"Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines"`

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. You will need to provide a little bit more details about your document so that we can better assist you. For example, start by providing a minimal working example that illustrates the problem hereby spoken of.

Comment: give us a clue: what does your source look like on lines 106-107 ?

Comment: @David Carlisle,Dear  David Carlisle,I found the code that cotains the `"~\\"` and `blank line`  always shows the warning imformation `"Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines"`

Comment: @tangshutao yes well, I could have guessed that it was `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph. Never do that.

Comment: Simply remove the  ` ~\\ ` It is always wrong to end a paragraph with `\\ ` (and always wrong to have `~` at the end of a line)

Answer (score 4):

You really don't want to set `\hfuzz` etc that way or tex will produce truly unreadable documents with no warning.

```
  \documentclass{ctexart}
   \usepackage{color}
   \usepackage{amsmath}
   \usepackage{amssymb}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage{epstopdf}
%   \hfuzz=\maxdimen
%   \tolerance=10000
%   \hbadness=10000
   \begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
(A \pm  B)^{-1} \neq A^{-1} \pm B^{-1} \quad (A \pm  B)^* \neq A^* \pm B^*\\
|(A^*)^*|=|A|^{n^2-2 n+1}
\end{gather*}

\end {document}
```